# translate3d+scale does not repaint on chrome 51

Tags: google-chrome, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

On chrome 51, why translate3d+scale gets blurry without transition? bug or expected? https://jsfiddle.net/hkzxwomy/2/

I does not happen with translate+scale, or scale alone

```
container.style.transform = `translate3d(10px, 10px, 10px) scale(${scale})`;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Chrome 53, if the element has will-change it will maintain this behavior, and without it Chrome will re-rasterize it

More: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5637351992721408

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vutotadido/1/edit?html,css,output

Explanation: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f8WS99F9GORWP_m74l_JfsTHgCrHkbEorHYu72D4Xag/edit#

Comment: The linked Google doc helped solved my problem. In my case, I called `requestAnimationFrame` with a function to set `style.transform = "none"` then, within that callback, set up another `requestAnimationFrame` to remove the attribute with `style.transform = ""`. That caused a re-raster which removed blurriness.